# Is there any extension to "optimize" the creation of maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

is there any extension to "optimize" the creation of maps in QGIS?
i searched the repository, but found nothing useful, maybe i searched in a wrong way..

there are some things i am really missing:

- rulers to place the map-elements,
- the possibility to use thousand-seperator,
- the possibility of changing the elements propertiers by right-click-menu or at least in an easier way as at the moment would be pretty nice.

Answer (score 5):

> rulers to place the map-elements,

In every map element's settings, it is possible to specify the position by entering the desired values.

> the possibility to use thousand-seperator,

If you mean formated numbers in labels, this feature has been added in the latest version (> 1.7.x). Formated numbers can be specified in new label options.

> the possibility of changing the elements propertiers by right-click-menu or at least in an easier way as at the moment would be pretty nice.

Right-click in print composer currently locks the element so that it cannot be moved by mistake. All properties are accessible via the panel on the right.

Comment: thx for the fast reply, underdark

i already used the positioning-option, but rulers are more "visual" and easier to handle, espacially when the position is meant to be realtive

i'm using 1.7.4 and i don't find any place to activate a "Tausender-Trennzeichen" like here -> 123'456 for my nice swiss coordinates.

so, thanks a lot

kreike

Comment: do you mean for the coordinates of the grid? Print Composer has a lot of potential for improvement but so far no potential sponsor has come forth.